# Only getting On entry for Do While Loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm frustrated that I can't figure this out. Have tried few different types of loops to display a Multiplication table. All I get it one line in the label. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

    Dim intNum As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim intAnswer As Integer
    Dim myString As String

    Integer.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, intCount)
    intNum = 0

    Do While intNum < 12
        intNum = intNum + 1
        intAnswer = intNum * intCount
        lblTable.Text = "    " & intNum.ToString() & " * " & intCount.ToString() & " = " & intAnswer.ToString()
    Loop
```

Comment: Fall in the pit of success by always use StringBuilder to construct long strings.   And by using ListView with View=Details to display a grid of values.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are assigning the result of your loop to the same label, so you will only have one label.

If you want to create multiple labels you should be creating them as you go:

```
Dim top_pos as integer = 30 ' first label's Top
Dim left_pos as integer = 30 ' first label's Left


For intNum = 1 to 12  ' Im assuming you want the table from 1 to 12

    intAnswer = intNum * intCount
    Dim lbl As New Label
    With lbl
        .text = Cstr(intNum) & " * " & Cstr(intCount) & " = " & Cstr(intAnswer)
        .location = New Point(left_pos,top_pos) 'set its position
        ... 'and so on
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    End With

    top_pos = top_pos + 30 ' moves the position for the next label.

Next
```

[image: See The result]]

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, every time the code loops it sets the label text to the current result, while overwriting the previous result.

If you want the label to display multiple lines of data, you can try something like this:

```
lblTable.Text &= "    " & intNum.ToString() & " * " & intCount.ToString() & " = " & intAnswer.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
```

The "Environment.NewLine" at the end will add the newline between each result.

The "&" before the "=" is used to append to the end of the existing text. This is simlar to doing:

```
lblTable.Text = lblTable.Text & "..." & Environment.NewLine
```

Also, just a side note. If you want multiple lines in a label, you may need to set the AutoSize property to false and configure the desired size of the label properly.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
lblTable.Text = "    " & intNum.ToString() & " * " & intCount.ToString() & " = " & intAnswer.ToString()
```

it is only storing the last result.

You will need to pre-pend the existing results to the new results.

```
Label1.Text &= "    " & intNum.ToString() & " * " & intCount.ToString() & " = " & intAnswer.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
```

I added a `&` before the `=` so that the new results will be appended to the end of the existing contents of `Label1` and a NewLine on the end to make it a little neater

Comment: Thank You...all responses were very helpful